# How to return a result from an async task?

Tags: c#, async-await

I would like to return a string result from an async task.

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () => await audatex.UploadInvoice(assessment, fileName));

public async Task UploadInvoice(string assessment, string fileName)
{
    //Do stuff
    return string;
}
```

Async programming confuses me, can someone please explain it?

Comment: What did you try / what is the issue?  A quick google comes up with [How to: Return a Value from a Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537613(v=vs.110).aspx).  You need to change `Task` to `Task<string>`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your method should return `Task<string>` , not `Task`:

```
public async Task<string> UploadInvoice(string assessment, string fileName)
{
    //Do stuff
    return "some string";
}
```

Comment: How would i then call it?

Comment: @Pomster as I have mentioned: `string result = await UploadInvoice("", "")`

Comment: The await operator needs to be within a async and return type task. if i add the Task.Run(async () => wait UploadInvoice .. I get the error .. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>' to 'string'

Answer (score 54):

Async programming can take a while to get your head around, so I'll post what has been useful for me in case it helps anyone else.

If you want to separate the business logic from the async code, you can keep your UploadInvoice method async-free:

```
private string UploadInvoice(string assessment, string filename)
{
    // Do stuff    
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    return "55";
}
```

Then you can create an async wrapper:

```
private async Task<string> UploadInvoiceAsync(string assessment, string filename)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => UploadInvoice(assessment, filename));
}
```

Giving you the choice of which to call:

```
public async Task CallFromAsync()
{
    string blockingInvoiceId = UploadInvoice("assessment1", "filename");
    
    string asyncInvoiceId = await UploadInvoiceAsync("assessment1", "filename");
}
```

Sometimes you might need to call an async method from a non-async method.

```
// Call the async method from a non-async method
public void CallFromNonAsync()
{
    string blockingInvoiceId = UploadInvoice("assessment1", "filename");
                
    Task<string> task = UploadInvoiceAsync("assessment1", "filename");
        string invoiceIdAsync = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

----EDIT: Adding more examples because people have found this useful----

Sometimes you want to wait on a task, or continue a task with a method on completion. Here's a working example you can run in a console application.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var program = new Program();
        program.Run();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    
    async void Run()
    {
        // Example 1
        Console.WriteLine("#1: Upload invoice synchronously");
        var receipt = UploadInvoice("1");
        Console.WriteLine("Upload #1 Completed!");
        Console.WriteLine();
    
        // Example 2
        Console.WriteLine("#2: Upload invoice asynchronously, do stuff while you wait");
        var upload = UploadInvoiceAsync("2");
        while (!upload.IsCompleted)
        {
            // Do stuff while you wait
            Console.WriteLine("...waiting");
            Thread.Sleep(900);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Upload #2 Completed!");
        Console.WriteLine();
    
        // Example 3
        Console.WriteLine("#3: Wait on async upload");
        await UploadInvoiceAsync("3");
        Console.WriteLine("Upload #3 Completed!");
        Console.WriteLine();
    
        // Example 4
        var upload4 = UploadInvoiceAsync("4").ContinueWith<string>(AfterUploadInvoice);
    }
    
    string AfterUploadInvoice(Task<string> input)
    {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Invoice receipt {0} handled.", input.Result));
        return input.Result;
    }
    
    string UploadInvoice(string id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Uploading invoice {0}...", id));
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Invoice {0} Uploaded!", id));
        return string.Format("<{0}:RECEIPT>", id); ;
    }

    Task<string> UploadInvoiceAsync(string id)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => UploadInvoice(id));
    }
}
```

Comment: CallFromNonAsync() can deadlock depending on whether or not this is a threadpool thread.

Comment: IMO @Joshua that seems beyond the scope of the question. This is very basic async code. But sure, in this case CallFromNonAsync should be run from the main UI thread, or from a threadpool thread, e.g. Task.Run(() => CallFromNonAsync()).

Comment: If you're on a threadpool thread, don't ever block waiting for a threadpool thread to finish. That's where the deadlock comes from.

Answer (score 7):

```
public async Task<string> UploadInvoice(string assessment, string fileName)
{
    string result = GetResultString();//Do stuff    
    return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Do this:

```
public async Task<string> UploadInvoice(string assessment, string fileName)
```

Then `await` the result:

`string result = await UploadInvoice("", "");`

More examples can be seen here:

[Async Return Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524395.aspx)

Comment: i get this error.     The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: you need to call it from within an `async` method which i guess you are not? try the following: `var myTask = Task.Run(() => a.UploadInvoice("", ""));
            string result = myTask.Result;`